# avoid Authorization in partial view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, authorize

that the code for my `homecontroller`.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
          [AllowAnonymous]
          public  PartialViewResult FB_InviteFriends()
          {
               return PartialView("~/Views/ListContats/_fbinvite.cshtml");
          } 
          [Authorize]
          public ActionResult YourZone()
          {
               return View();
          }
    }
```

i want to access the `FB_InviteFriends()` method `public/unAuthorized` users, by using this url:
`/Home/yourzone/FB_InviteFriends`
but it will redirect me to login page due to [Authorize] attribute. 
now my question is that is there any way that i can avoid the Authorization without removing the `[Authorize]` attribute as i need it on `yourzone`. any `global.asax` filter any route filter which may help.

Answer (score 3):

Add an exception to authorization for this path, e.g.

```
  <location path="Home/yourzone/FB_InviteFriends">    
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

you may have to adjust according to what authentication you use on your site.

Comment: thats the code i have added in web.config and still i can't access the page without logined in.

<location path="~/Home/YourZone/FB_InviteFriends">

    <system.webServer>

      <security>

        <authentication>

          <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />

          <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />

          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />

        </authentication>

      </security>

    </system.webServer>

  </location>

Comment: also i have tried that too:

<location path="~/Home/YourZone/FB_InviteFriends">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

but its not working too

Comment: try removing the tilda (~) from path

Comment: then i'm getting this error:
<location> path attribute must be a relative virtual path.  It cannot start with any of ' ' '.' '/' or '\'.

Comment: first thing is that when i'm trying your solution i get the error in 2nd line:  Unrecognized configuration section formsAuthenticationWrapper.
2nd if i removed that line and try again then as i said it redirect me to login page.

Comment: wrapper doesn't apply to your situation.  what is loading your partial view by the way?

Comment: i'm using @Ajax.ActionLink() to load the partial view. still i'm hunting for way to resolved the problem

Comment: I've not done this a partial view, how about having a simple View that also brings back the partial view within it?  As the partial might not get a route.

Comment: plz correct me what you want to say? 
currently yourzone will be simple view and it will bring back the partial view using the @Ajax.ActionLink(). which way i will do it now. i really appreciate your effect to help me.thanks

Comment: try changing your PartialViewResult to ActionResult on the action

Comment: i did this but still not working. can i add some kind of method in global.asax which will get the url and skip the Authorization for that path?